# How to open a TCP connection from a WebMatrix 3 project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, tcp, websocket, webmatrix

I need to talk to an external server that only accepts TCP connections and doesn't support HTTP connections.  I know the IP address and the port since the service is running on a Linux box I have in a Virtual Machine on Azure.  What I can't figure out is how to do this from a WebMatrix 3 project since it only supports .NET 4.0, not .NET 4.5, and 4.5 has the assemblies that support TCP client work.

I've tried to use the WebSocket4Net NuGet package, installed into WebMatrix 3, but I'm not sure connecting as a client TCP socket is what it does.  When I try connecting to the server using code like this (note, the URL is fake except for the "ws:" protocol prefix, the only prefix WebSocket4Net seems to support):

```
WebSocket4Net.WebSocket("ws://myazuredns.cloudapp.net:6721");
ws.Open();
```

The connection times out.  I know that the service at the foreign web site is active since I checked many times that the service is listening on the right port using netstat.  How can I do TCP client socket work from a WebMatrix 3 project?